# Unable to use MicroMeter instead Of Prometheus

Tags: spring-boot, metrics, prometheus, micrometer

I upgraded my Spring Version from 1.5 to 2.0 and upgraded Prometheus version 0.3.0 to 0.6.0. But unfortunately, it was not working. I was told I have to use `MicroMeter` instead of `SimpleClient` and added `io.micrometer` to my `pom.xml` and `@EnablePrometheusEndpointremoved` for my `MetricConfig` class but I come across with following error. Do you know why I get such kind of error ?

> Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException:
>   Error creating bean with name 'servletEndpointRegistrar' defined in
>   class path resource
>   [org/springframework/boot/actuate/autoconfigure/endpoint/web/ServletEndpointManagementContextConfiguration$WebMvcServletEndpointManagementContextConfiguration.class]:
>   Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is
>   org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to
>   instantiate
>   [org.springframework.boot.actuate.endpoint.web.ServletEndpointRegistrar]:
>   Factory method 'servletEndpointRegistrar' threw exception; nested
>   exception is
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException:
>   Error creating bean with name 'routeControllerEndpoint' defined in
>   class path resource
>   [org/apache/camel/spring/boot/actuate/endpoint/CamelRouteControllerEndpointAutoConfiguration.class]:
>   Unsatisfied dependency expressed through method
>   'routeControllerEndpoint' parameter 0; nested exception is
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error
>   creating bean with name 'camelContext' defined in class path resource
>   [org/apache/camel/spring/boot/CamelAutoConfiguration.class]:
>   Post-processing of merged bean definition failed; nested exception is
>   java.lang.IllegalStateException: Failed to introspect Class
>   [org.apache.camel.impl.DefaultCamelContext] from ClassLoader
>   [jdk.internal.loader.ClassLoaders$AppClassLoader@77556fd]

Comment: This usually happens due to different versions of spring modules being used. Using same version for all spring dependencies should help.

Comment: The Camel auto-configuration is failing so I don't see the link with Micrometer. Check that the camel version you are using is compatible with your Spring Boot version.

Comment: Which Camel Version I am supposed to use for Spring Boot 2.0 ? Do you have any advice for that ? I am using latest Camel Version 2.23.0.

Comment: @Tonyukuk Since 2.22 it seems to support Spring Boot 2. A simple sample project to reproduce the problem might be helpful.

Comment: Hello Johnny I have still same "camelContext" problem.Error creating bean with name 'camelContext' defined in class path resource CamelAutoConfiguration.class. Post-processing of merged bean definition failed; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: Failed to introspect Class [org.apache.camel.impl.DefaultCamelContext] fro.....

Comment: unfortunately still no resolution :(

Comment: Spring Boot 2 does not support Apache Camel 2.22 :( I still come across with same error. It should not that hard :(

Comment: hi.. did you find anything ?